# On Gitblit, how to upload my public key through the browser?

Tags: gitblit

It seems like it is possible to manage SSH keys through the webapp:
http://gitblit.com/setup_transport_ssh.html#H5

Unfortunately, I can't see the "the SSH Keys tab"
I can see only one tab: "repositories"

Configuration: Gitblit 1.5.1, Tomcat7, jdk7 on RH6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the current documentation but using the previous Gitblit release which didn't have this feature. [1.6.0 release notes](http://gitblit.com/releases.html#1.6.0)

Comment: Thanks James, for the response and Gitblit too!